# Horizontal list in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using ssrs 2005 to create a report. Currently my report is using a list which shows the data as,

```
testsuiteid1         testcase1   status1
                     testcase2   ststus2
                     testcase3   ststus3


testsuiteid2         testcase1   status1
                     testcase2   status2
```

I want to display the list horizontally like,

```
   testsuiteid1                            testsuiteid2
testcase1   status1                      testcase1   status1                       
testcase2   ststus2                      testcase2   status2   
testcase3   ststus3
```

The data set provides the test cases and their corresponding status grouped by the test suite id. Can i display the list horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly doable. You just need to make use of column groups.

Here is the dataset I used.

```
SELECT 'testsuite2' AS testsuite, 'testcase1' AS testcase, 'status1' AS status
UNION
SELECT 'testsuite2' AS testsuite, 'testcase2' AS testcase, 'status2' AS status
UNION
SELECT 'testsuite1' AS testsuite, 'testcase1' AS testcase, 'status1' AS status
UNION
SELECT 'testsuite1' AS testsuite, 'testcase2' AS testcase, 'status2' AS status
UNION
SELECT 'testsuite1' AS testsuite, 'testcase3' AS testcase, 'status3' AS status
```

1. Insert a blank table connected to the appropriate data set
2. Change the details row group to group on test case.
3. Populate the first field in the group with the testcase field.
4. Add a column group - a Parent group - and set it to group on testsuite.
5. Delete the empty table header row between the row containing testsuite and the row containing testcase.
6. Populate the cell next to testcase with the status field.
7. Delete the 2 columns that are outside of the column group.
8. Format the text and table as needed.

Your end result should look like this in design mode:
[image]

It will look like this on the report: 
[image]

Note: I made this with SSRS 2012, but I checked and I think these instructions will work for SSRS 2005.